# Phalcon webtools not working

Tags: php, phalcon

So I installed Phalcon and the phalcon devtools. When I try anything, it throws an error (Generate model, generate controller and scaffolding). Looked around and I can see other people had this problem but I cannot find a solution.

Generate Model page:

[image: Phalcon webtools generate model]

Error on generate:

[image: Phalcon webtools error]

webtools.config.php:

```
define('PTOOLS_IP', '192.168.0.81');
define('PTOOLSPATH', 'C:/phalcon-tools/vendor/phalcon/devtools');
```

Error on generate controller:

> Please specify a controller directory

Error on generate model:

> Database configuration cannot be loaded from your config file

Error on scaffolding:

> Adapter was not found in the config. Please specify a config variable [database][adapter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this same issue the other day. I found a work around but it's far from ideal.

Find

> \devtools\scripts\Phalcon\Builder\

And open Components.php

Inside this file find the line:

```
foreach (array('/app/config/', 'config/') as $configPath) {
```

This line needs to be either:

```
(array('/../app/config/'  <- For model Generator to work.
```

or

```
(array('../app/config/' <- For scaffolding Generator to work.
```

I can't for the life of me work why, and it's far from ideal trying to remember to do it every time you need to use the tools, but it works.

Comment: I saw this solution somewhere already, but it doesn't work for me. This is my first try on phalcon, is it always this buggy? Should I drop it?

Comment: This is the only bug I've encountered so far and in fairness it's not phalcon but an add-on like a bundle for symfony so I wouldn't blame them too much. Maybe the path set in your config is wrong to begin with?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to refresh everything, your solution works. :)

Comment: There is one problem with the answer though, models work with `/../` and controllers with `../`. You might wanna check that.

Comment: Had a feeling i'd got them wrong was going by which action I thought I'd done last. I'll swap then round now thank you.